# how to get value of int with ob_get_contents();

Tags: php

i m trying to get the value of an integer from getcontent !

i ve seen this solution with string

```
ob_start(); //Start output buffer
echo "abc123";
$output = ob_get_contents(); //Grab output
ob_end_clean(); //Discard output buffer
```

get int value :

```
ob_start(); //Start output buffer
echo "<script> document.writeln(document.getElementById('idinput').value) </script>" ;
$output = ob_get_contents(); //Grab output
echo $output; //
```

converting this output with $var = (int)$output did not work either ! any help ?

Comment: have you tried to use intval? http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: yes and it didn t work too !

Comment: may be the problem is with ob_get_content return type (buffer)

Answer (score 0):

ob_get_contents(); returns the value of the PHP output.
This is server side and before your client side code is executed.
It is not possible to read the value of an HTML input this way.

Comment: So how can I read the value of an input in php without the form method post or get?